# (Python Adafruit FT232H) When running the code for USB on windows it is reading a file that seems to not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, adafruit

I am trying to get the I2C to work from a laptop using the Adafruit FT232H board. I set it up and ran the i2cdetect code, and the I2C pin reads.

According to Adafruit if I used the file for Raspberry Pi and just modified the I2C lines it should read properly. However, when I ran the file it would not even read the file.

I get the error

> File "bicolor_matrix8x8_test.py", line 29, in 
>       display = BicolorMatrix8x8.BicolorMatrix8x8()   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Adafruit_LED_Backpack\BicolorMatrix8x8.py",
>   line 39, in **init**   File
>   "build\bdist.win32\egg\Adafruit_LED_Backpack\Matrix8x8.py", line 33,
>   in **init**   File
>   "build\bdist.win32\egg\Adafruit_LED_Backpack\HT16K33.py", line 47, in
>   **init**   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Adafruit_GPIO\I2C.py", line 63, in get_i2c_device   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Adafruit_GPIO\I2C.py",
>   line 43, in get_default_bus   File
>   "build\bdist.win32\egg\Adafruit_GPIO\Platform.py", line 34, in
>   platform_detect
>       #    History:   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Adafruit_GPIO\Platform.py", line 90, in
>   pi_version
>       # IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/cpuinfo'

The change I made is as follows on the **Adafruit_LED_Backpack/HT16k33.py** file, lines 45-56.

```
if i2c is None:
        FT232H.use_FT232H()
        ft232h = FT232H.FT232H()
        i2c = FT232H.I2CDevice(ft232h, 0x71)
        if i2c.ping():
            print 'found device'
        else:
            print 'device not found'
        #i2c = I2C
    #self._device = i2c.get_i2c_device(address, **kwargs)
    self._device = i2c
    self.buffer = bytearray([0]*16)
```

The entire [file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_RVm-TEpZYocGtTNUdPVlk4MFU) can be found in [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_RVm-TEpZYocGtTNUdPVlk4MFU)

I ran the **examples\bicolor_matrix8x8_test.py** file. And got the error above. When I removed the dependent files which were **Adafruit_LED_Backpack\atrix8x8.py** and **Adafruit_LED_Backpack\HT16k33.py** I still got the same error, but from my understanding I should get file not found error. This line

> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Adafruit_LED_Backpack\HT16K33.py", line 47, in
>    __ init __
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Adafruit_GPIO\I2C.py", line 63, in
>   get_i2c_device

should does not exist in **Adafruit_LED_Backpack\HT16K33.py** because I commented it line 54.

```
self._device = i2c.get_i2c_device(address, **kwargs)
```

and I couldn't find **egg** folder.

I guess my questions are:

- Why is the **egg** file being read?
- Why is my modified file being over looked?
- How can I fix it?

Comment: That library is for raspberry, not for a normal computer, where does adafruit say that it is portable for pc?

Comment: Yes that library is for raspberry pi, however by changing the **Adafruit_LED_Backpack\HT16K33.py** file with the above code and then running the setup.py again you can make the file work for PC

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I was supposed to run **setup.py** again after I made the changes for the changes to take place. Running it makes a new .egg file that is read by the programs in the **Adafruit_LED_Backpack/examples** folder. The changes I made was correct.